# call Api from server side not in client side

Tags: asp.net, api

How Can I call the Request Get (Api) from server side.

Here is the Server side

```
public string GetAllBook()
    {
        bookAssembly bookassembleur = new bookAssembly();
        bookList = bookassembleur.GetBooks();
    }
```

And here is the Api Request

```
 public List<Book> Get()
        {
            BookAssembly searchallbook = new BookAssembly();
            return searchallbook.GetBooks();


        bookAssembly bookassembleur = new bookAssembly();
        bookList = bookassembleur.GetBooks();
        DataTable dt = new DataTable();
        if (dt.Columns.Count == 0)
        {
            dt.Columns.Add("ID");
            dt.Columns.Add("Title");
            dt.Columns.Add("Price");
            dt.Columns.Add("Author");
            dt.Columns.Add("Qauntite");
            dt.Columns.Add("Categorie");
        }
        foreach (Book book in bookList)
        {
            DataRow NewRow = dt.NewRow();
            NewRow[0] = book.ID;
            NewRow[1] = book.Title;
            NewRow[2] = book.Price;
            NewRow[3] = book.Author;
            NewRow[4] = book.Qauntite;
            NewRow[5] = book.Categorie.Name;
            dt.Rows.Add(NewRow);
        }
        gvBook.DataSource = dt;
        gvBook.DataBind();
        return "";

    }
```

i want remove  bookList = bookassembleur.GetBooks() ana call api

Answer (score 0):

You have to access it using `HttpClient`.

e.g.

```
using (var client = new HttpClient())
{
    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("<your_api_path>");
    var response= client.GetAsync("GetAllBook");
    response.Wait();

    BookAssembly searchallbook = response.Result;

}
```

P.S. this is not running code, just an idea.

Answer (score 0):

```
  public string GetAllBook()
         {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://localhost:6735/api/book");
                //HTTP GET
                var responseTask = client.GetAsync("Book");
                responseTask.Wait();

                var result = responseTask.Result;
                if (result.IsSuccessStatusCode)
                {
                    var readTask = result.Content.ReadAsAsync<Book[]>();
                    readTask.Wait();
                    var Books = readTask.Result;
                    if (dt.Columns.Count == 0)
                    {
                        dt.Columns.Add("ID");
                        dt.Columns.Add("Title");
                        dt.Columns.Add("Price");
                        dt.Columns.Add("Author");
                        dt.Columns.Add("Qauntite");
                        dt.Columns.Add("Categorie");
                    }
                    foreach (Book book in Books)
                    {
                        DataRow NewRow = dt.NewRow();
                        NewRow[0] = book.ID;
                        NewRow[1] = book.Title;
                        NewRow[2] = book.Price;
                        NewRow[3] = book.Author;
                        NewRow[4] = book.Qauntite;
                        NewRow[5] = book.Categorie.Name;
                        dt.Rows.Add(NewRow);
                    }
                }
            }
            gvBook.DataSource = dt;
            gvBook.DataBind();
            return "";

        }
```